# How can I embed a word document in a web page in php

Tags: php, ms-word

I have a Word document that I would like to embed in the web page.
Right now, it is setup up the following way:
The iframe is loaded, and then it reads the following URL:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" style="border:0;width:100%;height:500px;" src="https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=?qa=view&id=<?php echo $fileId; ?>"></iframe>
```

Then it will go the QuickAction file, to read the following code:

```
  $contents = "/var/app/general/".$_GET['id'];

  $fileInfo = getRowById("kb_versioning",$_GET['id']);
  $fileType = $fileInfo['RevUserFileType'];
  $fileName = $fileInfo['RevUserFileName'];

  header("ContentEncoding: 'base64'");
  header("Content-type: $fileType");
  header("Content-Length: $fileName");
  readfile($contents);
  exit;
```

What will be the correct way of getting the file information from the S3 bucket and the word document to appear on the webpage using the following URL: https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?

Comment: Tell word (or a converter) to export it to html or convert it to PDF. You can not assume that a user want to install some strange browser addin. And by the way. A word doc is usually the most stupid file format for a text file :) Another way would be to parse the file with WORD and VBA to extract and convert the doc parts to a more web usable format.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

The problem was that I should have used a full URL.